# Mathematica 8 choppy surface plots on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: graphics, 14.04

Using Mathematica 8 on Ubuntu 14.04. While generating `SphericalPlot3D` with `ColorFuntion` the rendered graphics is very choppy. The smooth color variation seems pixelated. Initially on rotation the graphics was disappearing but running Mathematica with `mathematica -mesa` solved that problem. However graphics is still choppy.

Answer (score 0):

Try Edit->Preferences->Appearance->Graphics and turn on Anti-Aliasing... worked for me (Mathematica 9 on Ubuntu 14.04)